# Ошибка PHP

Tags: php

```
function resultSetToArray($result_set){
        $array = array();
        while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) != false){
            $array = $row;
        }
        return $array; 
}
```

php выдает такую ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in D:\Programs\OpenServer\domains\localhost\libs\functions.php on line 20
```

не знаю как исправить?

Comment: Извините, конечно, но вы эту ошибку [читать](http://translate.google.com/?source=osdd#auto|auto|Fatal+error%3A+Call+to+a+member+function+fetch_assoc()+on+a+non-object) пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

у вас **$result** неизвестно откуда берется, возможно вы имели в виду:

```
function resultSetToArray($result_set)
{ 
    $array = array(); 
    while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) != false)
    { $array[] = $row; } 
    return $array; 
}
```